# How to implode a generator?

Tags: php, generator

I have a [PHP generator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) which generates some `$key => $value`.

Is there an "easy" way to [`implode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the values (by passing the generator name)? Or to transform it to an array?

I can do this with a couple of lines of code, but are there some builtins functions to accomplish this?

Comment: try `iterator_to_array` function

Comment: Thanks! I should have searched for `iterator` instead of `generator` to find the answer.

Comment: answer has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function for the same, have a look on below example:

```
function gen_one_to_three() {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        // Note that $i is preserved between yields.
        yield $i;
    }
}

$generator = gen_one_to_three();

$array = iterator_to_array($generator);
print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One has to keep in mind that

> A generator is simply a function that returns an iterator.

For instance:

```
function digits() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
```

`digits` is a generator, `digits()` is an iterator.

Hence one should search for "iterator to array" functions, to find [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) (suggested by [Chetan Ameta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504870/3207406) )